# How to communicate with a separate application from c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an .exe that runs on my computer. How can I connect to it from c#?

For example notepad.exe is running. I would like to write in notepad from windows form app or console app form. How can I do that?

Comment: If I recall correctly `SendKeys` interacts with the active application and not a specified one. I'd prefer sending messages wherever possible(usually only games need lower level approaches)

Comment: @Code, yeah `AppActivate`, then `SendKeys`

Comment: You can't simply activate other programs. Usually you can do that only if you have focus yourself or when some event occurred.

Comment: can you be more specific? using SendKeys90 i'll be able to write in notepad from c#? will the text written in c# be visible in notepad after i run my c# code?

Comment: what do you mean by focused or event? can you please explain a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.thejaeck.net/2008/12/14/postmessage-in-c/). As far as I can tell, it does exactly what you are looking for. I realize it's in German, so just look at the source code.

Comment: thx a lot Thalaur. Did you download the source code? I have an error: resource file properties\resources.resx cannot be found. Can you please help me a little? thx. did in this code create an exe from the notepad exe and then run it?

Comment: Look at the source code in the article. First, they start the notepad application. Then, they get the window handle, and send messages to the window. With these window messages, you can Change the text (WM_SETTEXT), add text, and do many more. I did not compile the given program, it's just meant to show you how to do these things.

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

either start the process using Process.Start()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

or use SendKeys from Windows Script Host

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx

Comment: i knoe i can activate a .exe with process.start(). i was asking about how to send a text mesage to notepad from c#? i mean after bulding my c# code to see in notepad the string i've written in c#

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you want to do. Using [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the simplest solution but it's crude and limited in functionality. You can do more and better with [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but this will be harder to code.

Comment: can you tell me how could i do it? i want to be able to open the notepad exe and send data to it...and also read dates from it. it is possible?

Comment: @elisa: I can't give you a solution. Try on your own first.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from another process in windows is problematic to say the least. We did some work on this a while ago and it involved hooking into the low-level Win32 API using assembly language. Essentially, it's really not pleasant and if you can avoid doing this you'll have a lot more hair on your head.

Using SendMessage would work if the application you are sending to understands the message you are trying to send to it. I suspect that you start to get into security problems with this on later Windows versions (Vista + Win7) and would have to run your application with elevated privileges.

Why do you want to do this?

Comment: hi. i want to acces for example notepad and to read from it and write to it. i would also like to implement it as a windows service. I mean i would likt to access notepad from a windows service and send messages in it from my service